# Javamail and STARTTLS not working on different platforms

Tags: jakarta-mail, starttls

I created an example to send emails using STARTLS. Running it on 3 different windows versions hosted in different domains, everything works.

The  bizzare thing is that when I run it on a Ubuntu Server 14.02 LTS it doesn't works. There is no firewall blocking and the java application binaries are the same.

This is the code:

```
// Port we will connect to on the Amazon SES SMTP endpoint. We are choosing port 25 because we will use
// STARTTLS to encrypt the connection.
static final int PORT = 25;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    // Create a Properties object to contain connection configuration information.
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", PORT);

    // Set properties indicating that we want to use STARTTLS to encrypt the connection.
    // The SMTP session will begin on an unencrypted connection, and then the client
    // will issue a STARTTLS command to upgrade to an encrypted connection.
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.required", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "false");
    props.put("mail.debug", "true");

    // Create a Session object to represent a mail session with the specified properties. 
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);

    // Create a message with the specified information. 
    MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
    msg.setReplyTo(InternetAddress.parse("no-reply@no-host.com"));
    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(FROM));
    msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(TO));
    msg.setSubject(SUBJECT);
    msg.setContent(BODY, "html/plain");

    // Create a transport.        
    Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");

    // Send the message.
    try {
        System.out.println("Attempting to send an email through the Amazon SES SMTP interface...");

        // Connect to Amazon SES using the SMTP username and password you specified above.
        transport.connect(HOST, PORT, SMTP_USERNAME, SMTP_PASSWORD);

        // Send the email.
        transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
        System.out.println("Email sent!");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("The email was not sent.");
        System.out.println("Error message: " + ex.getMessage());
    } finally {
        // Close and terminate the connection.
        transport.close();
    }
}
```

This is the javamail log from a Windows environment (what is working):

```
DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.5.4
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle]}
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]}
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
Attempting to send an email through the Amazon SES SMTP interface...
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com", port 25, isSSL false
220 email-smtp.amazonaws.com ESMTP SimpleEmailService-1207632523 H3nxFSQJ7ktEpHBHuT38
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com", port: 25

EHLO roberton
250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com
250-8BITMIME
250-SIZE 10485760
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250 Ok
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "10485760"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "PLAIN LOGIN"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "Ok", arg ""
STARTTLS
220 Ready to start TLS
EHLO xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com
250-8BITMIME
250-SIZE 10485760
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250 Ok
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "10485760"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "PLAIN LOGIN"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "Ok", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate using mechanisms: LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 NTLM 
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN succeeded
DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
MAIL FROM:<naoresponder@xxxxxxxxx>
250 Ok
RCPT TO:<xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx>
250 Ok
DEBUG SMTP: Verified Addresses
DEBUG SMTP:   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
DATA
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
From: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Reply-To: xxxxxxxxxxxxx
To: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Message-ID: <1926764753.0.1448359358140@xxxxxxxx>
Subject: Amazon SES test (SMTP interface accessed using Java)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: html/plain
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

This email was sent through the Amazon SES SMTP interface by using Java.
.
250 Ok 0000015138f203b5-6fcd5424-60c3-43eb-9542-83699cf36c46-000000
DEBUG SMTP: message successfully delivered to mail server
Email sent!
QUIT
221 Bye
```

And this is the log from the Ubuntu (environment what isn't working):

```
DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.5.4
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle]}
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]}
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
Attempting to send an email through the Amazon SES SMTP interface...
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com", port 25, isSSL false
220 email-smtp.amazonaws.com ESMTP SimpleEmailService-1207632523 tIUsmWGoY4gXLCMWdUpi
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com", port: 25

EHLO xxxxxxxxx
250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com
250-8BITMIME
250-SIZE 10485760
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250 Ok
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "10485760"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "PLAIN LOGIN"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "Ok", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: STARTTLS required but not supported
The email was not sent.
Error message: STARTTLS is required but host does not support STARTTLS
```

This is the callstack error:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: STARTTLS is required but host does not support STARTTLS
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:719)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:364)
        at SESEmail.main(SESEmail.java:64)
```

Java version: 1.8.0_60-b27

Why this is happening?

Comment: what version of java do you use in windows machine and which on ubuntu?

Comment: And please provide as with the exact exception stacktrace...

Comment: As seen in return to EHLO in Ubuntu session: STARTTLS is not supported by that server (at that time?, from that source?). Is that reproducible? STARTTLS is never visible from that server? You should try telnetting email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com on port 25 and fire that EHLO hostname yourself

Comment: @Jan I tried with telnet, and on this server (linux) it never get the STARTTLS. I need to install some libraries to enable this?

Comment: I don't think so. More likely you need to check your network setup. The line "250-STARTTLS" is a response from Amazon's SMTP when asked about its capabilities. That should not change whereever you call that from. Could you check IP addresses you target (with ping or netstat while connected with telnet?)

Comment: @Jan I tried using the same IP address on linux and windows. From windows I get STARTTLS and from linux not!

Comment: did you verify connection endpoint with netstat while connection established? It's so weird that amazon should handle your linux box differently that all other servers?

Comment: @Jan thanks for your support, for now I solved (see my answer). My server is currently a VPS linux hosted by http://www.host1plus.com, I think AWS is handling my server differently. I cannot spend more time on this, I will tick them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using an official example from AWS SES http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-using-smtp-java.html , and this one was using port smtp 25 for TLS.

For some reason, this port (25) doesn't works with TLS in some of my enviroments.

After some research, I found this http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-connect.html and tried to use the default TLS port 587, and now it works in both of my environments (linux and windows).

I think this was a problem/behavior from AWS SES servers and not a Java Mail problem. I will try to report this for AWS team.